# Can't forward IP address to OpenVZ container

Tags: networking, ip, centos, openvz

I've just made a clean CentOs 6.4 x86_64 install with OpenVZ for virtualization.
I have a dedicated server at iWeb with 5 IP addresses.
I created a container and assigned it an IP address BUT when I access to that IP I access to the main node (the host) instead of the container, it seems like the IP isn't being forwared to the container.

I followed this guide: http://openvz.org/Quick_installation

I also have installed OpenVZ Control Panel.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you bound the IPs to the server's physical interface? If so remove them from the physical interface.

Have you enabled IP forwarding - in /etc/sysctl.conf:

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

It would help to see the output from:

ip addr

and

netstat -rn